# how can re-solve this sql query?

Tags: sql

```
--CREATE TABLE Table1 (IssNo INT,  Qty INT)
--INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (120,10)

--CREATE TABLE Table2 (IssNo INT,  Qty INT)
--INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (120,20)
--INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (124,30)
```

**Table1**

```
IssNo Qty
120 10
```

**Table2**

```
IssNo Qty
120 20
124 30
```

**use this also :**

> From Table1->
>
> substring(Table1.IssNo,1,2), at end I need to add "%" (eg) 12%

Now I need to check this like condition in table2 For Qty..And i need to add all Qty of 12% (eg) 20 and 30 will come..after SUM=> 50

My query is `Select Name,id,IssNo,address,Qty from Table1` (here Qty alone should be sum of Table2)

**Expected o/p**

```
IssNo    Qty
120      50(Sum of Qty from Table2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select t1.issno,(select sum(qty) from table2) as qty
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.issno=t2.issno;
```

OR

```
select t1.issno,(select sum(qty) from table2) as qty
from table1 t1;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea66e/12)

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
Select Table1.IssNo,Sum(Table2.Qty) as Qty
From Table1 inner join  Table2  
on  Cast(Table2.IssNo as varchar) like substring(cast(Table1.IssNo as varchar),1,2) + '%'  
Group By Table1.IssNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query.

```
declare @IssNo as varchar(10) -- whatever length you want

 select @IssNo =  substring(cast(Table1.IssNo as varchar),1,2) + '%'  from Table1

 Select Table2.IssNo,Sum(Table2.Qty) as Qty
 From Table2 
 Where Cast(Table2.IssNo as varchar) like @IssNo
 Group By Table2.IssNo
```

Comment: its was not coming the exact output... i need the output like         IssNo    Qty
120      50(Sum of Qty from Table2)